# How to pass a list of paths to spark.read.load?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I can load multiple files at once by passing multiple paths to the `load` method, e.g.

```
spark.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
  .load(
    "/data/src/entity1/2018-01-01",
    "/data/src/entity1/2018-01-12",
    "/data/src/entity1/2018-01-14")
```

I'd like to prepare a list of paths first and pass them to the `load` method, but I get the following compilation error:

```
val paths = Seq(
  "/data/src/entity1/2018-01-01",
  "/data/src/entity1/2018-01-12",
  "/data/src/entity1/2018-01-14")
spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(paths)

<console>:29: error: overloaded method value load with alternatives:
  (paths: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (path: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (List[String])spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(paths)
```

Why? How to pass a list of paths to the `load` method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need is a *splat* operator (`_*`) the `paths` list as

```
spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(paths: _*)
```

Comment: Why is the splat operator (_*) needed?

Answer (score 4):

`load` method support varargs type of argument, not the list type. So you have explicitly convert list to varargs adding `: _*` in load function.

```
spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(paths: _*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use the `paths` option, from Spark code source (ResolvedDataSource.scala):

```
val paths = {
            if (caseInsensitiveOptions.contains("paths") &&
              caseInsensitiveOptions.contains("path")) {
              throw new AnalysisException(s"Both path and paths options are present.")
            }
            caseInsensitiveOptions.get("paths")
              .map(_.split("(?<!\\\\),").map(StringUtils.unEscapeString(_, '\\', ',')))
              .getOrElse(Array(caseInsensitiveOptions("path")))
              .flatMap{ pathString =>
                val hdfsPath = new Path(pathString)
                val fs = hdfsPath.getFileSystem(sqlContext.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
                val qualified = hdfsPath.makeQualified(fs.getUri, fs.getWorkingDirectory)
                SparkHadoopUtil.get.globPathIfNecessary(qualified).map(_.toString)
              }
          }
```

So a simple:

```
sqlContext.read.option("paths", paths.mkString(",")).load()
```

Will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to create list. You can do like below

```
val df=spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").option("header","true").load("/data/src/entity1/*")
```

Comment: In my case i don't want every file to be loaded. If yes, then of course this would work.