# Discovering and reading multiple files in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Have got different systems which has different set of files(txt,csv) to be loaded and transformed and written to out files
using Apache Spark/Scala.
Say SystemA has 3 files and SystemB has got 2 files on their respective directories.

```
FileType       |FileNames
-----------------------------------------
Customer       |Customer_20190301.csv
Account        |Account_20190301.csv
Order          |Order_20190301.csv
OrderDetails   |OrderDetails_20190301.txt
Transactions   |Transactions_20190301.txt
```

Now I would like to get the file names and paths based on the system name given as an input so I can load their respective system files.
I don't want to create separate programs for each system and load their files as the filenames or paths could change in future.

Is there an efficient way of handling this? Using configuration files? 
Or may be using or not using any external libraries? Please guide me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890344/how-to-pass-a-list-of-paths-to-spark-read-load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is a good candidate for a divide & conquer approach:

1. Describe the number of systems + any parameters necessary to parameterize further processing. How you do this depends on your deployment environments, language of choice, etc. There is no one right answer.
2. Read the information from (1) into a data structure.
3. Generate a list of files to be processed using some combination of (2) and, perhaps, (recursive) directory listing. Note that given a path, you can get a Hadoop file system in Spark using `FileSystem.get(new java.net.URI(path), new Configuration())`.
4. Group the files by type.
5. For each group, parameterize a `DataFrameReader` from `spark.read` appropriately and call the many paths version of load using `.load(paths: _*)`. You can generalize this code by creating a map of group name to a function that returns a `DataFrameReader`.

Here is an example of how to do (5):

```
val readers: Map[String, SparkSession => DataFrameReader] = Map(
  "customer" -> ((spark: SparkSession) => spark.read.option("format", "csv"))
)

val groups: Map[String, Seq[String]] = ???

groups.map { case (groupName, paths) =>
  readers(groupName)(spark).load(paths: _*)
}
```

Comment: @@Sim, Thank you so much for your reply.
On 1) would that be advisable to maintain the Sytems and its corresponding filesets in a `configuration file` (Ex: Text file).
and load it into a `Map[String,Seq[String]]` for `groups`.

Something like this - 
`SytemA=Customer_20190301.csv`
`SytemB=Transactions_20190301.txt`

Would you recommend this?

Comment: I have no recommendation on how to store the configuration. That depends on who's authoring it, how much data is there, what language you are using, how/where you are deploying, etc. Use whatever is convenient. If you can write the configuration in a CSV file that Spark can read, that will save you some parsing.